# Blowfish Algo For a Image

Tags: c, encryption, blowfish

I am doing a project on image encyption. We are using the blowfish encyption on the image. According to Paul Kocher's Code http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html. The main function is as follows

```
void main(void) {
unsigned long L = 1, R = 2;
BLOWFISH_CTX ctx;

Blowfish_Init (&ctx, (unsigned char*)"TESTKEY", 7);
Blowfish_Encrypt(&ctx, &L, &R);
printf("%08lX %08lX\n", L, R);
if (L == 0xDF333FD2L && R == 0x30A71BB4L)
  printf("Test encryption OK.\n");
else
  printf("Test encryption failed.\n");
Blowfish_Decrypt(&ctx, &L, &R);
if (L == 1 && R == 2)
  printf("Test decryption OK.\n");
else
  printf("Test decryption failed.\n");
}
```

Here the author is using L=1 and L=2 to encrypt where as i will be using Image Pixels to encypt and the output will be hexadecimal Values. Now the problem is how will convert the output hexadecimal values into valid image formats like .jpg or .tiff so as to show it as Blowfish encypted image.

Or suggest me any other way if I can encrypt the image as a whole without encypting each pixels?

Need suggestion on this. THANKS in advance

Comment: Do you encrypt images's pixels, or image's file content? if the latter, it can't be saved back and read as a normal image, since encryption will have format blown up.

Comment: @charlesB Can u suggest me how can i encrypt the file content using the algorithm. There is no such algorithm available which works on file data but all algorithm uses numbers to do the encyption. If you have any ideas do let me know

Comment: You didn't answer the question. Pixel data and file data are different things, what data do you want to encode?

Comment: @charlesB I m fine with either of them. Whether pixel data or file data i want to encypt a image and then find the correlation and entrpy of the image. The output of the encyption should be a valid image file

Comment: Why would you use ECB? That's pretty much the worst choice for almost all applications.

Answer (score 0):

The library just encrypts one long integer into another long integer - it doesn't matter where this number is from.

All you have to do is loop over the pixels in your image, copy a long integer's worth (probably 32bits but depend son your platform) into the encrypt function and then copy the resulting long integer's worth of the encrypted ones into you other image.

The only decision you have to make is - do you want to encrypt the whole image file - including the header, or only the image data block?

If you encrypt the entire file you can use any other Blowfish utility to encrypt/decrypt it - but nobody will know it's an image. If you encrypt only the image block, other people will know that it's an image and be able to open it - but see a random picture - but they will only be able to encrypt/decrypt it with your software.

```
// assuming Blowfish_Encrypt is context,input,output
unsigned char *data = image.get_pointer_to_data();
int step = sizeof(unsigned long);
for (int y=0;y<rows;y++) {
   for (int x=0;x<cols;x+=step) {
      memcpy(&L,data,step);      
      Blowfish_Encrypt(&ctx, &L, &R);
      memcpy(data,&R,step);      
      data += step;
   }
}
```

Not an optomised solution, and you have to be a bit careful of padding - but shows you the general idea

Comment: I m using Matlab to calculate the entropy and correlation of the encypted image. So if i encypt the whole image i wont be able to read the image in matlab software. So wht i need is to encrypt the data block. So the problem is the output of the encryption is a hexadecimal number which is not a valid image date. So i need help on who to encrypt or decrypt the image and the output should be recognized by any image processing tool

Comment: @anupsahu - the output isn't a hex number, thats just how the printf shows it for you to read. It's an integer - just a block of 32, 0 and 1s in memory - that can be pixels or anything else